# Why is rubocop asking me to put // around regex when i'm using %r already?

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I have the following regex

```
  regexp = %r{
     ((returned|undelivered)\smail|mail\sdelivery(\sfailed)?)
  }x
```

But when I run rubocop on it, it complains that I need to "Use // around regular expression."

How can I get around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't run rubocop so not sure this will solve your problem. You can use // instead of {} to surround the regex when using %r:

```
regexp = %r/((returned|undelivered)\smail|mail\sdelivery(\sfailed)?)/x
```

Answer (score 3):

You can disable (and enable) any rubocop cop by adding a `.rubocop.yml` file to the root of your project folder and setting up the appropriate configurations. To see what you can do, check out the global `default.yml` in your rubocop package. It's fully commented.

For this particular problem, create a `.rubocop.yml` and...

To disable the cop completely:

`Style/RegexpLiteral:
  Enabled: false`

To *always* use `%r`:

`Style/RegexpLiteral:
  EnforcedStyle: percent_r`

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiline regexp with `/.../x` either:

```
regexp = /
  ((returned|undelivered)
  \s
  mail|mail
  \s
  delivery
  (\sfailed)?)
/x
```

See more in [Rubocop gem doc](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Style/RegexpLiteral)

Answer (score -2):

> when I run rubocop on it, it complains that I need to "Use // around regular expression."
>
> How can I get around it?

I think the message is pretty clear: to get around it, you can use `//` around the regular expression:

```
regexp = /((returned|undelivered)\smail|mail\sdelivery(\sfailed)?)/x
```